# Dense subspace and the annihilator of a set.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a linear normed space and $A$ a arbitrary subset then show that the closure of $\left<A\right>$ is dense iff the annihilator of $A$ is $\{0\}$ (the zero functional)

I try to use the Hahn - Banach theorem but i not sure to how aplying, i will very grateful for any suggestion or hint.

EDIT:

$(\Leftarrow)$ Sup. that exists $x \in  X- \overline{ \left<A\right>}$ then $x \notin \overline{ \left<A\right>}$ this implies that $d=d(x,\left<A\right>)>0$ for one corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem exists $g \in X^*$ such that $g|_{\overline{ \left<A\right>}}=0$ in particular $g|_{A}=0$ (because $A \subset \left<A\right>$)..(1) and $g(x)=d$ from (1) deduce that $g \in A^{\perp}$ but $A^{\perp}={0}$ then $g=0$ and that implies $g(x)=0$ but $g(x)=d>0$ and that is a contradiction, those not exists $x$ such that  $x \in  X- \overline{ \left<A\right>}$ and therefore $X=\overline{ \left<A\right>}$

EDIT (2)
The other direction i think to is from continuity and using the density

Comment: Hahn Banach Theorem is the right approach. Tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: i have one direction of the proff (see the edit) but in the other direction i not sure

Comment: Converse part is the trivial part. If $g$ is $0$ on $A$ and $A$ is dense then $g\equiv 0$.